# KineticJS setScale / Zoom issue - Random lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

If I set the scale / zoom with KineticJS I get a strange error. There appears random lines.

EDIT1: Okay. It looks like if I set the scaleRate to 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625 etc. it works. Is there any other fix?

EDIT2: Well. EDIT1 isn't really a fix. If I zoom the whole page (browser) the lines appear again.

---

http://jsfiddle.net/2trNz/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="zo">Zoom Out</a>
<a href="#" id="zi">Zoom In</a>
<div id="viewport"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'viewport',
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        });

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var tileWidth = tileHeight = 32;

for(var row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    for(var column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
        var tile = new Kinetic.Rect({
                                x: column * tileWidth,
                                y: row * tileHeight,
                                fill: "green",
                                width: tileWidth,
                                height: tileHeight,
                            });
        layer.add(tile);
    }  
}

stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();

var scale = 1;
var scaleRate = 0.05;
$("#zo").on('click', function(e) {
    scale -= scaleRate;
    layer.setScale(scale);
    stage.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#zi").on('click', function(e) {
    scale += scaleRate;
    layer.setScale(scale);
    stage.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is in rounding.
How to resolve:

add stroke

```
new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: column * tileWidth,
    y: row * tileHeight,
    fill: "green",
    width: tileWidth,
    height: tileHeight,
    stroke : "green"
});
```

or add green background

or increase tiles width and height

Answer (score 1):

The lines are voids where the tiles have grown apart because of the scaling.

You could stretch your tiles by 1px to cover the gap:

```
width: tileWidth+1,
height: tileHeight+1,
```